# React native and Realm Sync

Tags: react-native, realm

I have a problem with react native and realm sync. Where I am creating realm instance with sync object parameter, it works great and all data stores on the server, but when I disconnect the network connection, no data appears to load. It seems that realm doesn't store data locally. my code looks like this:

```
 let config = {
    user: user,
    url: "{path}/~/userRealm",
    error: err => alert(err)
};

Realm.open({ schema: schemas, schemaVersion: schemaVersion, sync: config })
    .then(realm => {
        const items = realm.objects('Department').sorted('name', true);
        resolve(items);
    })
    .catch(error => {
        alert(error);
        reject(error);
    });
```

Comment: Just to understand you correctly: when your mobile is online, you can see the data in your app? And once you set it offline, you cannot see the data? Moreover, you see the data on the server (using Realm Studio)?

Comment: yes when it online is fine, but when it goes offline realm open hangs and does nothing

Comment: Which version of Realm JS do you use? Do you see it only on Android or iOS or both?